# Gui Interactions

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

This is my first time creating a Gui and I'm stumped on how to create interactions.

I'm trying to implement a single selection mode when the combobox is on single, and multiple when it's placed on multiple. I placed them on the multi line comment.

Any ideas?

> //Interactions
>
> //When “Single” is selected then the JList changes so only one item
>   can be selected.
>
> //When “Multiple” is selected, the JList changes so multiple items can
>   be selected
>
> //When a country, or multiple countries, is selected the JLabel
>   changes to reflect the new selections

```
public class GuiTest {


public static String[] Countries = {"Africa", "Haiti", "USA", "Poland", "Russia", "Canada", "Mexico", "Cuba"};
public static String[] Selection = {"Single", "Multiple"};

JPanel p = new JPanel();
JButton b = new JButton("Testing");
JComboBox jc = new JComboBox(Selection);

JList jl = new JList(Countries);


private static void constructGUI() {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Countries Selection");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    // add a JLabel that says Welcome
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Selected Items:");
    frame.add(label);
    frame.pack();



    JComboBox jc = new JComboBox(Selection);
    frame.add(jc);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);


    JList jl = new JList(Countries);
    frame.add(jl);
    frame.pack();



    JComponent panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panel.add(new JLabel("Choose Selection Mode:"));
    panel.add(jc);
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(jl, BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);



}




public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            constructGUI();

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: You're layout looks broken since you're adding all of your components more than once, and with different constraints. What is the current out put your getting and what do you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

you should start adding the modes to the ComboBox:

```
comboBoxCategoria.addItem("Single",0);
comboBoxCategoria.addItem("Multiple",1);
```

then add a ActionListener to your ComboBox to modify the list selection mode

```
jc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    if(jc.getSelectedItem().equals("Single")){
      jl.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    }else{//must equals
      jl.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    }
  }
});
```

finally add a MouseListener on the list to detect changes on the list selections and  change the JLabel to reflect the new selections

```
jl.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { 
    label.setText(list.getSelectedValuesList().toString());
  }
});
```

edit: you should also add a KeyListener to update the label since the selection can be changed via arrow keys

```
jl.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    label.setText(list.getSelectedValuesList().toString());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
    jc.addActionListener((evt) -> {
        if ("Single".equals(jc.getSelectedItem())) {
            jl.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
            int[] sel = jl.getSelectedIndices();
            if (sel != null && sel.length > 1) {
                jl.setSelectedIndex(sel[0]);
            }
        } else {
            jl.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        }
    });
    jl.addListSelectionListener((evt) -> {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        for (Object o: jl.getSelectedValuesList()) {
            if (buf.length() > 0) {
                buf.append(", ");
            }
            buf.append(o);
        }
        label.setText(buf.toString());
    });
    jc.setSelectedItem("Single");
```